# JQUERY Listen for click event

Tags: jquery, onclick, slide, listen

What i'm looking for is to have my container resize onclick.

Inside the container are 2 panels that slide down with varied heights. I need the container to listen for the toggle function and resize if needed.

Heres the code so far...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var content = $("#content_container");  
    var childHeight = $('.panel-container').height();

    if (content < childHeight) {
        $(content).css("height", 657 + "px");
    }

    else {
        $(content).css("height", "auto");
    }

});
```

PS. I'm new to jQuery!!

Comment: set the height of your container to auto will not work???

Answer (score 0):

You can with something like below, I am not sure if this is what you want but you can mess around with it and get it how you want it to be;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#content_container").toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({height: 657}, 200);
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this).animate({height: 200}, 200);
        }
    );

});
```

A working example http://jsfiddle.net/CarlG/x6yLj/2/